# Problem with aligning picture and NAV section in fixed header

Tags: html, css, flexbox, styling

I am trying to place logo and NAV section by using flexbox method. For some reason it is not aligning. Also can someone explain what did I do wrong 
I can try to use "float" property but I want to do it only by using flexbox method.

```css
body {
       margin: 0;
       font-family: "Helvetica", "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
       color: seashell;
       background-color: black;
       font-size: 22px;
       text-align: center;
       opacity: 0.9;
      }

    a {
      color: seashell;
      }

    .flex-container {
       display: flex;
       justify-content: center;
       flex-wrap: wrap;
      }

    header {
       width: 100%;
       position: fixed;
       z-index: 1;
       height: 69px;
       background-color: black;
       border-bottom: 1px solid seashell;
       align-items: center;
      }

    header img {
       height: 50px;
       padding-left: 10px;
      }

    nav {
       text-align: right;
       flex-grow: 1;
      }

    nav span {
       display: inline-block;
       padding: 20px 10px;
      }
```

```html
<header class="flex-contaner">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy- 
             content/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-tea-cozy-logo.png">
    <nav>
        <span><a href="#mission">Mission</a></span>
        <span><a href="#tea-of-the-month">Tea of the Month</a></span>
        <span><a href="#locations">Locations</a></span>
    </nav>
</header>
```

I have checked my code with some other solutions and found that they are using the same code and it works for them but not for me. I am checking results in Google Chrome

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding `display: inline-block;` to the `nav`, this will get them to display inline together.

```css
body {
       margin: 0;
       font-family: "Helvetica", "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
       color: seashell;
       background-color: black;
       font-size: 22px;
       text-align: center;
       opacity: 0.9;
      }

    a {
      color: seashell;
      }

    .flex-container {
       display: flex;
       justify-content: center;
       flex-wrap: wrap;
      }

    header {
       width: 100%;
       position: fixed;
       z-index: 1;
       height: 69px;
       background-color: black;
       border-bottom: 1px solid seashell;
       align-items: center;
      }

    header img {
       height: 50px;
       padding-left: 10px;
      }

    nav {
       text-align: right;
       flex-grow: 1;
display: inline-block;
      }

    nav span {
       display: inline-block;
       padding: 20px 10px;
      }
```

```html
<header class="flex-contaner">
            <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy- 
             content/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-tea-cozy-logo.png">
              <nav>
                <span><a href="#mission">Mission</a></span>
                <span><a href="#tea-of-the-month">Tea of the Month</a></span>
                <span><a href="#locations">Locations</a></span>
              </nav>
      </header>
```

Comment: I have tried and it doesn't work. Also I already have it for "nav span"

Comment: Do you think you could create an illustration based of what is the intended behavior. Because my code snippet shows the two items inline.

Comment: In my browser logo is centered and NAV is on the right side but under the header

Comment: I'm still confused, is that what is currently happening or what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what are you trying to do ?
use Display : flex; at header since it is the parent container for the flex elements.

```css
body {
       margin: 0;
       font-family: "Helvetica", "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
       color: seashell;
       background-color: black;
       font-size: 22px;
       text-align: center;
       opacity: 0.9;
      }

    a {
      color: seashell;
      }

    .flex-container {
       display: flex;
       flex-wrap: wrap;
      }

    header {
       width: 100%;
       position: fixed;
       z-index: 1;
       height: 69px;
       background-color: black;
       border-bottom: 1px solid seashell;
       align-items: center;
       display:flex;
      }

    header img {
       height: 50px;
       padding-left: 10px;
      }

    nav {
       text-align: right;
       flex-grow: 1;
      }

    nav span {
       display: inline-block;
       padding: 20px 10px;
      }
```

```html
<header class="flex-container">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/fff/11">
              <nav>
                <span><a href="#mission">Mission</a></span>
                <span><a href="#tea-of-the-month">Tea of the Month</a></span>
                <span><a href="#locations">Locations</a></span>
              </nav>
      </header>
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks! Still I am a bit confused why it worked for this other guy who did not have  "display: flex" property in header, but only in class ".flex-container"

Comment: @PredragAranđelović the container spelling is wrong in yours, first user's code and the first user hasnt used the flex property on the header rather he has used display-inline. But i have used display flex at the flex container and so both using display flex and display inline works